# Web App (Struts framework) - Java - ClassNotFoundException Error

Tags: java, weblogic, struts, intellij-14

I am creating some Java classes in the existing Web App using Struts 1.x framework. I use IntelliJ and Java language. In the error log, there are showing 2 following errors:

> ERROR 2015-09-17 13:31:11,668 org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils - Error creating form bean of class test.web.approvals.forms.TestingForm
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.st.web.approvals.forms.TestingForm
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
>       at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.applicationClass(RequestUtils.java:207)
>       at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.applicationInstance(RequestUtils.java:231)
>       at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.createActionForm(RequestUtils.java:837)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionForm(RequestProcessor.java:364)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:253)
>       at test.st.web.base.OWSRequestProcessor.process(OWSRequestProcessor.java:183)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1485)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:509)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
>       at test.st.web.access.sso.LoginCacFilter.doFilter(LoginCacFilter.java:53)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>   ERROR 2015-09-17 13:31:11,668 org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor - No action instance for path /test_inbox could be created
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.st.web.approvals.actions.TestingInboxAction
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
>       at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.applicationClass(RequestUtils.java:207)
>       at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.applicationInstance(RequestUtils.java:231)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionCreate(RequestProcessor.java:326)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:268)
>       at test.st.web.base.OWSRequestProcessor.process(OWSRequestProcessor.java:183)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1485)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:509)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
>       at test.st.web.access.sso.LoginCacFilter.doFilter(LoginCacFilter.java:53)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

How should I fix these errors?

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` is pretty clear, your class isn't found. Your application structure is built incorrectly (what does your .ear/.war file look like) or your server start params are wrong (what is your server's classpath? check the log file)

Comment: The struts is too old to run under weblogic, make sure you have very old weblogic to be able to run with struts. The status of Struts is EOL.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the exception mentions:

The class TestingForm is not under directories: 
 test.web.approvals.forms

which must be under WEB-INF/classes or in a jar file under WEB-INF/lib